# Java Mode method

Tags: java

I have to write a method to find all modes in a `double[]` and return them as an `ArrayList`. So far my code works, but adds the mode multiple times to the `ArrayList`. here's my code:

```
public static ArrayList<Double> mode(double[] a){
    double[] copy = copy(a);
    sort(copy);
    ArrayList<Double> modes = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int count = 0;
    int maxCount = 0;
    double number;
    double possibleMatch;
    double currentMode;
    for(int i = 0; i<copy.length-1; i++){
        number = copy[i];
        possibleMatch = copy[i+1];
        if (number == possibleMatch){
            count++; //need to reset for each unique val
        }
        if(count == maxCount && count != 0)
            modes.add(number);
        if(count > maxCount){
            modes.removeAll(modes);
            currentMode = possibleMatch;
            modes.add(currentMode);
            maxCount = count;
        }
        if(number != possibleMatch)
            count = 0;
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < modes.size()-1; j++){
        if(modes.get(j) == modes.get(j+1))
            modes.remove(j+1);
    }
    return modes;
}
```

copy and sort are utility methods to sort the array low-high and copy it so that sorting does not change the original array.

Comment: You could use `Set` instead of `List` to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help... here is my new code. It seems to be working.

```
    public static ArrayList<Double> mode(double[] a){
    double[] copy = copy(a);
    sort(copy);
    ArrayList<Double> modes = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int count = 0;
    int maxCount = 0;
    int uniqueVals = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<copy.length-1; i++){
        if (copy[i] == copy[i+1])
            count++;
        else {
            uniqueVals++;
            count = 0;
        }
        if(count == maxCount && count != 0)
            modes.add(copy[i]);
        if(count > maxCount){
            modes.clear();
            modes.add(copy[i]);
            maxCount = count;
        }
    }
    if(modes.size() == uniqueVals)
        modes.clear();
    return modes;
}
```